# Site Url in Azure resource group

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-resource-manager, azureportal

Is there a way to get/create a Site Url (eg: abcdefg.cloudapp.net) for a Azure resource group just like the one in Azure Cloud Services ?

Comment: a URL identifies a single resource, not a group of them... what would you want the URL to resolve to?

Comment: The url would be used to provide access to applications at different tcp ports hosted on different VM's.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have a few options:
1) you can give each VM it's own publicIP and dns and access the VMs via their individual URLs/IPs
2) you can put all the VMs behind a loadbalancer, give the loadbalancer the publicIP address and set up NAT rules to redirect to each VM via a specific port on the URL/IP.

Does that help?